# Javascript maturity on Blackberry, Android, Windows Phone 7 and iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, blackberry, windows-mobile

What is the state of maturity of javascript on these platforms? Is safe write a prototype app and trust that it'll work on all of these devices without headaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Android and iOS devices use a [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) based browser, so the Javascript support is relatively mature compared to other phones.  The new Blackberry Torch also has a [WebKit based browser](http://blogs.blackberry.com/2010/02/blackberry-developer-day-round-up/) and its Javascript speeds are tremendously better than the old BB browsers.  WP7 uses a newer version of IE, but I haven't read much else about it.

Some advice: It isn't safe to assume anything when programming Javascript that you want to work **properly** in all the different mobile browsers (sadly the same could be said about desktop browsers).

I know each of these devices provide an emulator you can test on (iOS is Mac only), so I suggest booting them all up if you really want to make sure your web application works on each of them.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475674/what-javascript-events-are-available-to-webkit-on-android) is another SO question that you might want to look at if you are using any kind of events on your mobile application