# Prevent scroll bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, event-bubbling

How can I prevent scroll bubbling?

The following example isn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Scroll Bubbling</title>
        <style>
            #menu {
                width: 80px;
                height: 150px;
                background: red;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function isScrollOnBound( scrollContainer ) {
                if ( $( scrollContainer ).scrollTop() === 0 || 
                     $( scrollContainer ).scrollTop() + $( scrollContainer ).innerHeight() >= $( scrollContainer )[0].scrollHeight ) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $(function() {                  
                $( '#menu' ).on( 'scroll', function(e) {
                    if ( isScrollOnBound( this ) ) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }                   
                });

                $( window ).on( 'scroll', function(e) {
                    alert( 'stopPropagation not working' );
                });                 
            });     
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>  
        page 1<br />page 2<br />page 3<br />page 4<br />page 5<br />page 6<br />page 7<br />page 8<br />page 9<br />page 10<br />page 11<br />page 12<br />page 13<br />page 14<br />page 15<br />page 16<br />page 17<br />page 18<br />page 19<br />page 20<br />page 21<br />page 22<br />page 23<br />page 24<br />page 25
        <div id="menu">
            menu 1<br />menu 2<br />menu 3<br />menu 4<br />menu 5<br />menu 6<br />menu 7<br />menu 8<br />menu 9<br />menu 10
        </div>
        page 26<br />page 27<br />page 28<br />page 29<br />page 30<br />page 31<br />page 32<br />page 33<br />page 34<br />page 35<br />page 36<br />page 37<br />page 38<br />page 39<br />page 40<br />page 41<br />page 42<br />page 43<br />page 44<br />page 45<br />page 46<br />page 47<br />page 48<br />page 49<br />page 50
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459676/prevent-scroll-bubbling-from-element-to-window) why what you're trying to do doesn't work. It's not supposed to.

I've come across [one reliable method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element) to achieve what, I'm guessing, you want.

### Using [Brandon Aaron's plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2DwyH/) | Code

```
var menu = $('#menu')

menu.on('mousewheel', function(e, d) {
    if((this.scrollTop === (menu[0].scrollHeight - menu.height()) && d < 0) || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

<sub>Note: It does work in IE as well, it's just that when JSFiddle includes the plugin, IE returns a mime mismatch error. IE sucks.</sub>

Comment: This example works fine on iOS but doesn't work on Android, any idea why?

Comment: @Diogo No, I don't have much experience with android to be honest, but I'm guessing android uses a non-standard name for the event, or that event doesn't exist. Brandon's plugin uses the following to attach event handlers: `DOMMouseScroll`, `mousewheel` and `onmousescroll`. At the top of the plugin, you can add additional event names that the handler should hook to.

Comment: @Diogo Although, according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/476718/944301), the `DOMMouseScroll` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `touchmove` to the `document` (I think) and return `false`, meaning don't do anything. Only bind this when needed (when scrolling in your `div`) then unbind it as scrolling finishes.

I had the same issue with the parent being scrolled when I don't want it to and this is the only way I could solve it.

Do the following when you need the document to not scroll:

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(){
    return false;
});
```

And unbind when you are done:

```
$(document).unbind('touchmove');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try setContentHeight() to solve your problem.